# How to pass optional ID to Laravel Controller from Route?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I want to pass an ID to my controller from Routes:

```
Route::get('user/{id?}', function ($id= null) {
    return $id;
});
```

However, I'm not sure where to put the controller name and function?

```
MyController@get
```

Laravel's documentation and other questions don't seem to be related to this issue.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple for you. You almost done

```
Route::get('user/{id?}', YourControllerNameController@get);
```

In your controller

```
public function get($id = null){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Route

```
Route::get('/user/{id}','UserController@User');
```

Now you can access this id in AppSettings controller inside User function

User Function inside controller

```
public function User($id)
{
    \Log::alert($id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do it like this:

In routes/web.php

```
Route::get('user/{name?}', 'UserController@getName');
```

In UserController.php

```
public function getName(Request $Request, $name = null){

}
```

Comment: Is it possible by get method pass value `Request $Request`

Comment: @A.ANoman Request is automatically injected into any controller function if you pass `Request $Request` as the first parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment Symlink